# How to use chartjs-plugin-annotation in Angular

Tags: angular, chart.js

My versions in the Angular project are:
"chart.js": "^2.9.2",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",

On typing the import statement:

```
import * as ChartAnnotation from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
```

I am getting this on hovering above it

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'chartjs-plugin-annotation'. 'c:/XRay/xray/node_modules/chartjs-plugin-annotation/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/chartjs-plugin-annotation` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';`ts(7016)
```

I am trying to make a line on my scatter chart by using this

```js
this.scatterChart = new Chart('myChart', {

        type: 'scatter',
        //plugins: [ChartAnnotation],
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Scatter Dataset',
                pointBackgroundColor: ['yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'indigo'],

                data: [
                  { x: -10, y: 0 }, 
                    { x: 0, y: 10 }, 
                    { x: 3, y: 8 }, 
                    { x: 1, y: 4 }, 
                    { x: 9, y: 1 }, 
                    { x: -1, y: 5 }
                ]
            }]
        },
        options: {
          legend: {
            display: false
          },

            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom'
                }]
            },
            annotation:{
              drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
              annotations:[{
              type: 'line',
              id: 'vline',
              mode: 'horizontal',
              yscaleID: 'y-axis-0',
              value: 5,
              borderColor: 'green',
              borderWidth: 1,
              label: {
                enabled: false,
                content: 'Test label'
              }
            }]
          }
        } as ChartOptions


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me after I changed the import statement to:

```
var ChartAnnotation=require('chartjs-plugin-annotation');
```

and changed scaleID from x-axis-0 to x-axis-1:

```
annotation: {
      annotations: [
          {
              type: 'line',
              mode: 'vertical',
              scaleID: 'x-axis-1',
              value: avgXValue,
              borderColor: 'red',
              borderWidth: 2,
          },
          {
            type: 'line',
              mode: 'horizontal',
              scaleID: 'y-axis-1',
              value: avgYValue,
              borderColor: 'red',
              borderWidth: 2,
          }
      ]
  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever import libraries this way in a typescript project. If you lack a typescript definition, you can define an interface of the type any to avoid the error